# dividing column that contains blanks pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,10,10],'b':[10,'',0]})
df
    a   b
0   10  1o
1   10  
2   10  0
```

I want:

```
df['c']=df['a']/df['b']
```

but get error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

but I need the result to be a blank, and want

```
df['c] = [1,'',inf]
```

suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repalce` it will `NaN`, then fill it back

```
(df['a']/df['b'].replace('',np.nan)).fillna('')
Out[162]: 
0      1
1       
2    inf
dtype: object
```